# How to copy USB flash drive Ubuntu to boot onto internal NVME SSD?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, ssd, windows-10

So I have a USB Flash Drive Ubuntu with preinstalled stuff from my job. I wanted to move this to my much faster internal NVME SSD. I have to hit <kbd>f11</kbd> at my computer start to get a boot screen. Then I would select the Ubuntu that pops up and it loads into my employers' software.

It does this slowly though and takes up a precious USB port. How can I just copy the contents of the flash drive and just put it onto my NVME SSD? Below are the methods I tried.

1. Just simply copying all the contents with a right click to my main drive. I then shut down the PC, turned it back on, hit <kbd>f11</kbd>. But the selection for the ubuntu will not pop up.
2. I tried creating a virtual hdd on my main drive. That also didn't work.

Is there anything I can do? I'm willing to retry method 1 and 2. Maybe I did them wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In Windows 10 shrink the NVMe volume by 16 GB + the size of data files you have. Then install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. Then copy the data files (not the programs) to the NVMe drive.

Comment: Windows does not normally read Linux filesystems. You can install Diskinternals Linux Reader: https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/ This will allow Windows to view and copy your Linux USB.

Comment: Is flash drive a bootable drive? You cannot easily just copy it and have it be bootable. You can copy data. Best to do a new install to NVMe drive and copy data & /home if you have a lot of custom configuration in /home.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I just found out that I can't do that. The client will not allow it. So that is why I had a hard time to try and copy it and boot it up internally.

I had to ask our personal IT. Still, thank you to the people who answered.